# Resque saving to Development database instead of Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, jobs, resque

I'm using Resque for the first time to handle my delayed jobs.

My procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 "QUEUE=*" bundle exec rake resque:work
scheduler: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

My Job:

```
module Ballot
  @queue = :votes

  def self.perform(vote)
    @vote = Vote.new(vote)
    @vote.save!
  end
end
```

initializer/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
```

initializer/resque.rb

```
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development' 
resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
```

When I run this on my local machine, it works as expected. When I run this on heroku, it ends up saving to my local DB. If I'm not running a server locally, it'll wait until I start my local server to run all of the resque jobs and saves it locally.

Comment: What do you mean when you run it on Heroku it writes to your local DB? This is pretty much impossible because Heroku (running publicly on AWS) can't access internal IP addresses on your home network?

Comment: So you understand my bewilderment?

Comment: Turns out I had my development pointing to the Redis Url on production. This has stopped using my local machine, but I still can't get it to run on the production environment.